# Usar valor armazenado e redirecionar para página escolhida

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma `dropdown list` que tira as suas opções de uma base de dados `mysql`. O valor é armazenado numa variável com o Script Js. O botão devolve-nos a informação selecionada na opção 3. Depois de selecionar o valor ele é guardado em uma variável.

Vamos dizer que eu escolha uma opção "ABC" e guardo em uma variável, então quero usar essa variável para abrir um arquivo `html` chamado `ABC.html` no meu localhost.

Basicamente o objetivo é redirecioanr o usuário para a página relacioando com sua escolha.

aqui meu Script:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
function getOption() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("choosedOP");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>
        <title>ComboBox Ajax, PHP y MySQL</title>
        <script src="includes/js.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="getOp1();">

        <div id="op1"></div> <br />

        <div id="op2"></div> <br />

        <div id="op3"></div>
        <input type="button" onclick="getOption()" value="Click Me!">
    </form>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Como posso fazer para ao acionar o botão "click Me", o utilizador seja redirecionado para a página escolhida ? Ou seja, usar o valor da `var obj`
e abrir a página com o nome armazenado.

Por exemplo, ao escolher a opção ABC , é redirecionado para uma página localhost/abc.html ?

Comment: 1- Qual o conteúdo de `js.js` ?  2- Vejo um fechamento da tag `</form>`, mas não vejo sua abertura . 3-  Não consigo identificar o identificador `choosedOP`. E finalizando isso não deveria estar sendo realizado através do elemento `select`?

Comment: Este codigo funciona de acordo com o pretendido. Esta a selecionar os elementos das 3 ops e a indicar a op escolhida através do botão click me. o problema não é esse.

Agora, em vez de indicar a op escolhida, pretendia que ao carregar no botao click me, o user fosse redirecionado para a pagina com o nome da var obj.   Sei que tenho que substituir/ acrescentar o  comando window.location.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function redirect()
{
    var obj = document.getElementById("cbx_localidad");
    var redir =obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
    window.location.href = redir;
      }
```

Era tão simples quanto isto